# the android_expand partition in the sd on android can be resized?

Tags: linux, partitions, sd-card

Can the  android_expand partition be resize?

I need change the SD because start  to fails but i have a lot of thing on the SD partition well i try `dd if=/dev/mySD of=/dev/NewSD` both are same capacity even same brand but  fails whit `not enough space let`  and the partition get corrupted then android do not read it, i have done that in a bigger SD in the past and works but right now i have not posses a bigger SD then 64 GB then i need shrink the partition, It is possible ? sorry i post something from android here but I'm using Linux and it is related to part and i have ask the same in android enthusiast but no one answer Thank you !